# HTML5 validation when the input type is not "submit"

Tags: html, forms, validation

I'm using HTML5 for validating fields. I'm submitting the form using JavaScript on a button click. But the HTML5 validation doesn't work. It works only when then input type is [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit). Can we do anything other than using JavaScript validation or changing the type to `submit`?

This is the HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="example" name="example" value="" required>
<button type="button"  onclick="submitform()" id="save">Save</button>
```

I'm submitting the form in the function `submitform()`.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The HTML5 form validation process is limited to situations where the form is being submitted via a submit button. The [Form submission algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-algorithm) explicitly says that validation is not performed when the form is submitted via the `submit()` method. Apparently, the idea is that if you submit a form via JavaScript, you are supposed to do validation.

However, you can request (static) form validation against the constraints defined by HTML5 attributes, using the `checkValidity()` method. If you would like to display the same error messages as the browser would do in HTML5 form validation, I’m afraid you would need to check all the constrained fields, since the `validityMessage` property is a property of fields (controls), not the form. In the case of a single constrained field, as in the case presented, this is trivial of course:

```
function submitform() {
  var f = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
  if(f.checkValidity()) {
    f.submit();
  } else {
    alert(document.getElementById('example').validationMessage);
  }
}
```

Comment: can we use two buttons in a single form it shows error required fields alerts for both buttons why? how to solve?

Comment: @HTMLDeveloper, you should present your problem, with code, as a new question (and formulate it in more detail – I really can’t see what you are asking here).

Comment: Thanks for the simple example and explanation, it works for me.  The `alert` can be simplified to `alert(f.validationMessage);` in the code sample in case you are looping through :-)

Answer (score 14):

You should use form tag enclosing your inputs. And input type submit.
This works.

```
<form id="testform">
<input type="text" id="example" name="example"  required>
<button type="submit"  onclick="submitform()" id="save">Save</button>
</form>
```

Since HTML5 Validation works only with submit button you have to keep it there.
You can avoid the form submission though when valid  by preventing the default action by writing event handler for form.

```
document.getElementById('testform').onsubmit= function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
}
```

This will give your validation when invalid and will not submit form when valid.

Comment: Thats what I did.There is form tag.I asked is there any way other than using submit button

Answer (score 14):

I may be late, but the way I did it was to create a hidden submit input, and calling it's click handler upon submit. Something like (using jquery for simplicity):

```
<input type="text" id="example" name="example" value="" required>
<button type="button"  onclick="submitform()" id="save">Save</button>
<input id="submit_handle" type="submit" style="display: none">

<script>
function submitform() {
    $('#submit_handle').click();
}
</script>
```

Comment: This works for me, but how I detect in the code that the validation fail? That is because I want to interrupt the save functionality in the case of invalid field. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to add a new way of doing this that I just recently ran into. Even though form validation doesn't run when you submit the form using the `submit()` method, there's nothing stopping you from clicking a submit button programmatically. Even if it's hidden.

Having a form:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="title" required />
    <button style="display: none;" type="submit" id="submit-button">Not Shown</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="doFancyStuff()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This will trigger form validation:

```
function doFancyStuff() {
    $("#submit-button").click();
}
```

Or without jQuery

```
function doFancyStuff() {
    document.getElementById("submit-button").click();
}
```

In my case, I do a bunch of validation and calculations when the fake submit button is pressed, if my manual validation fails, then I know I can programmatically click the hidden submit button and display form validation.

Here's a VERY simple jsfiddle showing the concept:

https://jsfiddle.net/45vxjz87/1/

Comment: Please read the question "Can we do anything other than using js validation or changing the type to submit ?"

Answer (score 5):

Either you can change the button type to `submit`

```
<button type="submit"  onclick="submitform()" id="save">Save</button>
```

Or you can hide the submit button, keep another button with type="button" and have click event for that button

```
<form>
    <button style="display: none;" type="submit" >Hidden button</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with `<button type="submit">` you can perform the functionality of `submitform()` by doing  `<form ....... onsubmit="submitform()">`

Comment: @Ahmed.This won't work in my case.if the button type is submit the HTML5 validations will work.But I have many other js validations and so the return false will not work if the button type is submit

Comment: `submitform()` should work in form tag. what error are you seeing in console or its simply submitting the form without performing other validations?

Comment: yes its submitting the form without performing other validations

Comment: then its better to perform text field validations in `submitform()` as html5's `required` works with submit button

Answer (score 4):

2019 update: Reporting validation errors is now made easier than a the time of the accepted answer by the use of [HTMLFormElement.reportValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) which not only checks validity like `checkValidity()` but also reports validation errors to the user.

> The HTMLFormElement.reportValidity() method returns true if the element's child controls satisfy their validation constraints. When false is returned, cancelable invalid events are fired for each invalid child and validation problems are reported to the user.

Updated solution snippet:

```
function submitform() {
  var f = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
  if(f.reportValidity()) {
    f.submit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 Validation Work Only When button type will be submit

change --

```
<button type="button"  onclick="submitform()" id="save">Save</button>
```

To --

```
<button type="submit"  onclick="submitform()" id="save">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test
    {
        alert("hello world");  //write your logic here like ajax
    }
</script>

<form action="javascript:test();" >
    firstName : <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" required/><br/>
    lastName : <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" required/><br/>
    email : <input type="email" name="email" id="email"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Get It!" name="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```