# Alert when html5 validation fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

So what I need is simply an alert to appear when my html5 validation fails, like :

```
alert("Error, please fill all required fields before submitting.");
```

Is there some kind of event that I could use to show this alert using JavaScript or jQuery?

This seems really basic, but I couldn't find anything online about it. All I can find are ways to change the pop up message that appears directly on the field.

I need this because my forms spans over multiples tabs, so the bubble displaying an error message may not always appear depending on where the user is when he submits the form.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's `invalid` event fired on inputs if they don't pass validation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/invalid

Using jQuery you could do something like this:

```
$('input[required]').on('invalid', function(e){
  alert("Error, please fill all required fields before submitting.");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/644Lou8k/1/

Comment: I'd change the `$('input[required]').[...]` to `$(':input[required]').[...]` (notice the `:`) to include textareas into this. @pawel, consider editing your answer, please.

Answer (score 5):

For those who don't want to use jQuery:

```js
var requiredInput = document.getElementById('requiredField');

function showAlert(){
  alert("Error, please fill all required fields before submitting.");
}

requiredInput.addEventListener("invalid", showAlert, false);
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input id="requiredField" type="text" placeholder="Required input" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can capture the form submission event using javascript and validate/check for values before allowing it to go through.

```
$('form').submit(function () {
  if($('#blah').val() == "") {
    alert('blahblah');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

The HTML5 validation kicks in when the user submits the form and it does not raise any event. The only way is to have your own JS validation like many others have mentioned in their answers. Here is a good answer [HTML5 required validation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707743/html5-required-validation-not-working)

> The HTML5 form validation process is limited to situations where the
>   form is being submitted via a submit button. The Form submission
>   algorithm explicitly says that validation is not performed when the
>   form is submitted via the submit() method. Apparently, the idea is
>   that if you submit a form via JavaScript, you are supposed to do
>   validation