# Validate input type=number min=... single field, no form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an

```
<input type=number min=0 id='myinput'><button ....>
```

and some ajax which fires when the button is pressed.

If I enter a value outside the allowed range of the number, the border of the field becomes red, and I guess if it were a form, it wouldn't be submitted.

But my javascript doesn't know if the browser likes the input or not.

It is for an internal site, and I know that all users use a modern browser.

Can I check if the browser thinks the number is valid in my script which processes the button?

```
if ($("#myinput").BrowserSaysInputIsValid()) {...}
```

I don't have a form, as I just have a number of number-files with corresponding buttons and actions.

It is a stock management system.

```
[ 1 ][Move to Dept 1]
[ 0 ][Move to Dept 2]
```

So you enter a number and press the number next to it, and the javascript fires ajax changes. (It is done this way, because A: you most the time only do one action. B: It's more difficult to check that you dont move 10 to dept 1 and 20 to dept 2 and only have 20 in stock, if both moves are processed at the same time.)

Do I HAVE to build a form around each  ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707743/html5-required-validation-not-working

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-form-checkvalidity