# How to keep my user in the same page when a certain value is not correct

Tags: javascript, php

So, I am trying to create a little script that should check whether the data filled out by the user is correct or not, my problem however: even if it isn't right, it will throw the alert and then STILL redirect the user to the page where the check will be done (I think maybe because the action of my form field is to send you over there?). My question: How do I keep the user in the same page when the alert pops up that something has not been filled out correctly (without losing the values of the input fields either)?

The code I have:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        header('Location: errorHandler.php');
        exit();
    } else {
            $email =$_POST['email'];
            $usrName =$_POST['userName'];
            $pwd =$_POST['password'];
            $pwdConfirm =$_POST['confirmPassword'];

        if ($email !== $email) {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
                echo 'alert("It seems your email was not correct.")';
            echo '</script>';
        } else if ($usrName !== $usrName) {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
                echo 'alert("It seems your username was not correct.")';
            echo '</script>';
        } else if ($pwd !== $pwdConfirm) {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
                echo 'alert("it seems the passwords do NOT match")';
            echo '</script>';
        } else {
            include_once 'db.inc.php';

            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_POST['email']);
            $usrName =  mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_POST['userName']);
            $pwd =  mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_POST['password']);
            $pwdConfirm =  mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_POST['confirmPassword']);

            $sqli = "INSERT INTO logindb (email, name, password) VALUES ('$email', '$usrName', '$pwd')";

            mysqli_query($conn, $sqli);
        }
    }
```

How the input fields are created:

```
function getEblock() {
    let eBlock = ($('<div/>', {
        'class': 'col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 well'
    }));
    return eBlock;
}

function getEmail() {
    let email = ($('<input/>', {
        'type': 'email',
        'name': 'email',
        'placeholder': 'Fill out your e-mail...',
        'required': true,
        'class': 'form form-control'
    }));
    return email;
}

function getUserName() {
    let userName = ($('<input/>', {
        'type': 'text',
        'name': 'userName',
        'placeholder': 'Fill out your username...',
        'required': true,
        'class': 'form form-control'
    }));
    return userName;
}

function getPassword() {
    let password = ($('<input/>', {
        'type': 'password',
        'name': 'password',
        'placeholder': 'Fill out your password...',
        'required': true,
        'class': 'form form-control'
    }));
    return password;
}

function getConfirmPassword() {
    let confirmPassword = ($('<input/>', {
        'type': 'password',
        'name': 'confirmPassword',
        'placeholder': 'Confirm your password...',
        'required': true,
        'class': 'form form-control'
    }));
    return confirmPassword;
}

function getConfirmBtn() {
    let submitBtn = ($('<button/>', {
        'type': 'submit',
        'name': 'submit',
        'class': 'btn btn-info',
        'id': 'submitBtn'
    })).text('Submit');

    return submitBtn;
}
```

Yes, I know the way I am inserting everything into the table of my db sucks and I know I have to encrypt the pwd etc. but for now I am wondering how I can prevent the user from (still) going to `save.php`. My HTML won't show you much since the input fields etc. are made by javascript.

Comment: Are your input elements added to a `<form>` element?

Comment: Yes. I appended them all to the form field and it all works fine (when submitting). But the moment the user does not fill out the password and password confirm correctly it throws in an alert, the alert does show, but when you click "oke" it still redirects you to the save.php page. I could use the header() function, but this will cause the page probably to reset and therefore lose it's value i'm 100% certain of.

Comment: If you are wrapping your elements in a `<form>` tag, then you will need to prevent the default behavior of the form. `e.preventDefault();`.

Comment: A better idea would be to handle your validation logic on client side before redirecting to another page. then you can do `if(validate()){ //do redirect }` validate being a function that handles your validation where the default value will be true, and if a validation fails, it should return false.

Comment: Ah... that's a good one @Martin. I'll look into that.\

Comment: @JanDoe look into AJAX.

Comment: If you are trying to use HTML5 form validation and are adding these to a form element, what you are doing should work - see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drxf38q9/7/). If you are actually submitting using javascript, you will need to manually validate the fields: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16708619/2336208

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned per my comment, you can do some basic validation client side before parsing your data to your other page.

You can then do a double validation on your other page if you are comparing the user input values to other variables, for example data extracted from your database.

In my exmple I will generally use jQuery notations and AJAX.

A basic markup of your client side validation:

```
function validate() {
    var email = $("[name='email']").val();
    var userName = $("[name='userName']").val();
    var password = $("[name='password']").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("[name='confirmPassword']").val();

    var result = true;

    if(/* some E-mail validation */) {
        result = false;
    }

    if(/* some userName validation */) {
        result = false;
    }

    if(/* some password validation */) {
        result = false;
    }

    if(/* some confirmPassword validation */) {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

And your AJAX function:

```
function submitForm() {
    if( validate() ) {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/your_page.php",
            data : {
                submit: "1",
                email: $("[name='email']").val(),
                userName: $("[name='userName']").val(),
                password: $("[name='password']").val(),
                confirmPassword: $("[name='confirmPassword']").val()
            },
            success: function (html) {
                //do something on success
                if( html.includes('emailError') ) {
                    alert("It seems your email was not correct.");
                }
                else if( html.includes('userNameError') ) {
                    alert("It seems your username was not correct.");
                }
                else if( html.includes('passwordConfirmError') ) {
                    alert("it seems the passwords do NOT match")
                }
                else {
                    window.location.href = "/your_redirect_page.php";
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The AJAX function in this case is encapsulated in another function I chose to name *submitForm()*. You can call that function via your button using *onclick*.

Example:

`<button onclick="submitForm();">Click to submit</button>`

I'll Explain the success function in the AJAX function in a bit. It's basically a logic that revolves around your *server side* validation that you are doing.

Your PHP page with validation:

```
if($_POST['submit'] != "") {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $usrName = $_POST['userName'];
    $pwd = $_POST['password'];
    $pwdConfirm = $_POST['confirmPassword'];

    if($email !== $email) {
        echo 'emailError';
    }
    else if($usrName !== $usrName) {
        echo 'userNameError';
    }
    else if($pwd !== $pwdConfirm) {
            echo 'passwordConfirmError';
    }
    else {
        include_once 'db.inc.php';

        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_POST['email']);
        $usrName =  mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_POST['userName']);
        $pwd =  mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_POST['password']);
        $pwdConfirm =  mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_POST['confirmPassword']);

        $sqli = "INSERT INTO logindb (email, name, password) VALUES ('$email', '$usrName', '$pwd')";

        mysqli_query($conn, $sqli);
    }
}
```

If you look at the PHP code's validation, you can see that I choose to echo a string depending on the validation. Our AJAX' success function basically checks to see if the HTML includes any of those strings and throws the error message according to that. If everything is okay, it will continue to do the database logic, and redirect to another page.

Now, some of the code is mainly markup to make you understand, and isn't actually logically applicable, since we compare the *exact* same variables to one another in some cases. However, it should be more than enough to give you the general idea of how to implement a functional solution.