# Submit HTML button and onclick Overrides HTML5 required field

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have my code snippet this way:

```
<input type= "text" required="required" /><input type="submit />
```

The form validation happens only when there is no `onclick` parameter in the input attribute.

But I need to do further process in my JS file. So onclick function is needed for me along with the `required` parameter in it.

I am looking for something like:

```
<input type="text" required="required" /><input type="submit" onclick=signUp() />
```

But both `onclick` and `required` are not being taken together. any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707743/html5-validation-when-the-input-type-is-not-submit This Helped me.

Answer (score 0):

so run function after user make changes in text field simple

```
<input type= "text" required="required" onChange="signUp()" /><input type="submit />
```

Comment: He wants the function to run when the submit button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can try some JS validations and  trigger the submit after validation like

```
$(document).click("#id", function (){
  if($("#id").val() == ""){
    return false
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a few lines of javascript and it will work. You could add:

```js
    document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
        if(document.querySelector('input').value == ''){//if the user enters an Empty string,
            console.log('field empty');
        } else {console.log('not empty');}
    }
```

```html
    <input type="text" />&nbsp; <button>Submit</button>
```